# Delay For Menu Hover In Mouse Out

Tags: javascript, css, joomla

I have used RocketTheme Joomla Templates.

I have Try to Delay for Menu hover.

I want used following css for Delay in menu hover. And it's working. Please check link - [www.test2.guru99.com/](http://www.test2.guru99.com/)

```
.gf-menu li .dropdown {
transition: opacity 5.0s ease-out 0.0s;
}
```

My Requirement is -
when the mouse is moved out menu still appear for seconds.

My site url is - [www.test2.guru99.com/](http://www.test2.guru99.com/)

Please Help me!

Answer (score 2):

> transition: [animationTime] [delayTime] ...

```css
li > ul{
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition: 0.5s 2s; /* put the mouseleave wait time here */
}
li:hover > ul{
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  transition: 0.5s 0s; /* put the mouseenter wait time here */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>List item (will take 2sec to fade out)</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Sub-List item 1</a></li>
      <li><a>Sub-List item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

On mouseenter the `:hover` will trigger, and there's the `transition delay` rule of `0s` (no delay).
On mouseleave the initial rule will be used (`2s` delay).